# Change UIWindow frame animated

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, reachability, uiwindow

Is there any way to change UIWindow animated while being visible and key?

I want to implement such behaviour when network connection disappeared. I want to squeeze content that is displayed at that moment a bit and add a notification between controllers and the status bar. Something similar to what happened in iOS 12 and before, when you have active call or geolocation usage.

I can't transform my controller, because it must be above transition stack in the iOS 13. 
Or I should discuss it with designers if it completely impossible.

[image: What is drawn by designers]

What I found that you can't change the frame after you inited and presented window by setting new frame. As well as setting Transform.

```swift
   var frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
   frame.origin.y = 60
   frame.size.height -= 60
   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.frame = frame

   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 60)
```